# aws cli on ubuntu server vs amazon linux

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using aws-cli to download application configuration on startup. I'm testing it both on the Amazon Linux AMI and Ubuntu Server AMI, on the Ubuntu server I install the cli via apt-get awscli.

To both instances I have set the same IAM role with read access to S3. On the Amazon Linux instance I am able to download the configuration with the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://myconfbucket/conf.json conf.json
```

and it resolves the region by itself. On the Ubuntu Server instance I have to provide -- region eu-west-1.

How is the Amazon Linux instance able to resolve the region and how could I get the same behaviour on the Ubuntu Server instance?

Answer (score 2):

Has the `aws configure` command been run on the Amazon Linux machine at some point? Does that machine have a `~/.aws` directory with some config files in it? I'm pretty sure the CLI on both instances would be defaulting to the `us-east-1` region unless there was a configuration file specifying a different default region.

Comment: `aws configure` has not been called neither is there a ~/.aws folder (for ec2user). The bucket is also in eu-west-1.

Comment: Well that's really weird. Are they both running the same version of the AWS CLI? You can check by running `aws --version`.

Comment: they are running different versions. amazon linux: aws-cli/1.10.1 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.23
and Ubuntu:  aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic

I will try to install 1.10.1  on ubuntu and see if I get the same behaviour.

Comment: take a copy of the ~/.aws from the AWS Linux ami ? store it on the S3? Pull it down on startup as well? hard codes the config tho..